# How to emit whole list only once even if range() operator iterate itself corresponding to range passed in it

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

**Problem**
I am having a list which is coming from the backend after calling some API, I need to convert that list into some other type of list. Afterward, I need to add n number of an empty object into the final list. (n number is coming from some logic which suits my application.)

To solve this problem I have written the following code :

```
Observable.fromIterable(snipList).map(new Function<UserSnipModel, TaskContent>() {
        @Override
        public TaskContent apply(UserSnipModel userSnipModel) throws Exception {
            String displayName = userSnipModel.getDisplayName();
            TaskContent.Fields fields = new TaskContent.Fields(userSnipModel.getId(),
                    displayName, userSnipModel.getUrlCall(), userSnipModel.getRemarks(), userSnipModel.isEnableCall());
            Drawable icon = DrawableUtils.getDrawable(HomeActivity.this, userSnipModel.getIconName(), R.drawable.ic_diamond);
            return new TaskContent(fields, icon);
        }
    }).toList().toObservable().flatMap(new Function<List<TaskContent>, ObservableSource<List<TaskContent>>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<List<TaskContent>> apply(List<TaskContent> taskContents) throws Exception {
            return Observable.range(0, totalNumberOfMembers - numberOfItems).map(new Function<Integer, List<TaskContent>>() {
                @Override
                public List<TaskContent> apply(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    taskContents.add(new TaskContent(new TaskContent.Fields("",
                            "", "", "", false), null));
                    return taskContents;
                }
            });
        }
    })
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).safeSubscribe(new Observer<ListTaskContent>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<TaskContent> taskContents) {
        //This method is called  multiple time.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
        }
    });
```

When I run this, `onNext()` is called multiple time which is not working as expected. To handle this problem I added `toList()` inside the `flatMap()` then I got `List<List<TastContent>>` which is also not expected as I need only `List<TaskContent>`

What can I do to handle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `range()` emits several times, which means you emit your list (same one) several times. I think you should not try to be fancy with it and just add required number items inside the list with plain iteration, not using observables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this solution:

```
Observable.fromIterable(list)
    .map(item -> item.concat("new")) //Converting the items in the initial list
    .toList()
    .flatMap(data -> Single.zip(
            Single.just(data), //Mapped data set
            Observable.range(0, data.size()) //Empty list generator
                    .map(rangeVal -> rangeVal.toString())
                    .toList(),
            (initialList, emptyList) -> {
                initialList.addAll(emptyList); //Appending lists
                return initialList;
            }
            )
    )
    .subscribe(data -> {}, error -> {});
```